# Write a script containing a loop that lists all .png files in a single directory, then pipe it to the md5sum command

Tags: linux, loops, scripting, pipe, md5sum

How do I write a script containing a **loop** that lists all of the **.png** files inside a **single directory**, then **pipe** the output to the **md5sum** command so I can read the hash?  I do not want to have an individual hash for each file. I just want to read the hash for all the .png files combined.  Would I use tar?  I've created a separate file for the md5 output.  Just trying to connect the dots.  Thank you.

Comment: Please update your title to summarize what you're asking about. "New to Linux and scripting" doesn't tell us anything. Also, it's not clear whether you want an md5 checksum of the names of the files or of their contents.

Comment: You don't need a loop for either the names or the contents of the files, btw.

Comment: Keith Thompson, that's fair.  I am currently going through the Linux Essentials (LXE) course.  I've been tasked with completing the following task (verbatim): "Write a script containing a loop that lists all of the png files inside that directory.  Pipe the output to the md5sum command and grab the first 5 characters."  The textbook I've been provided (Linux Essentials-2nd Edition) shows basic scripting (i.e. variables, commands, loops, etc...).  However, it does not discuss how to do a task like the one I described, and the instructions are vague.

Comment: Here is the script so far.  I'm sure there's plenty wrong with it, but if anyone could help, I would appreciate it.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/bash
# sums.md5 created for loop output

$d"/usr/share/zenity"
$ for $d 'ls {*.png}' > sums.md5
$ do
$  md5sum sums.md5 | less
$ done

Comment: SO is not a free coding service, you know.

Comment: After a short test it seems that just a `cat *.png | md5sum` would do the job.

Comment: @Roadowl, I absolutely understand.  I assure you that my interest is purely academic.  I was simply stuck on an issue and could not figure out the answer, so I asked those who probably know.

Comment: @U880D.  Thank you.  That did just what I asked for.  A single MD5 Hash for all the .png files combined.